# The object is not getting added to the ArrayList. How to fix this problem?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I'm making console app for Planting house. House has 6 rows and each row has 25 Sections. I built this structure using arraylists of rows and sections. Now I want to add plants  to the section from user input. I

I have tried multiple ways to do it creating different methods which you can see in the comments but nothing is working, the Object Plant is either not getting created or not getting added to ArrayList plants.

```
public class Section {
private int number;
private List<TomatoPlant> plants;

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public Section(int number, List<TomatoPlant> plants) {
    this.number = number;
    this.plants = plants;
}

public Section(int number){
   this.number=number;
    //this.addPlants();
   this.plants= new ArrayList<>();
}

public List getPlants() {
    return this.plants;
}

public void addPlants(Cocktailtomatos cocktailtomato) {
    //this.plants= new ArrayList<>();
    this.plants.add(cocktailtomato);
    this.plants.add(Cocktailtomatos.createCocktailtomato("ss", "A", 1));
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Section{" +
            "number=" + number +
            ", plants=" + plants +
            '}';
}

public void addPlant(String id, String row, int sectionnumber) {
    Cocktailtomatos cocktailtomato = new Cocktailtomatos(id, row, sectionnumber, true, false, false, 0, 10);
    this.addPlants(cocktailtomato);
}
}







public class Manager {
private static Manager ourInstance = new Manager();

public static Manager getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

private Manager() {
}

Planthouse planthouse = new Planthouse();

public void addCocktailTomato(){
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Input Id:");
   String id = scanner.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Input Row");
   String row = scanner.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Input sectionnumber");
   Integer sectionnumber = scanner.nextInt();
   //Cocktailtomatos cocktailtomato = Cocktailtomatos.createCocktailtomato(id, row, sectionnumber);
   //cocktailtomato.setId(row + sectionnumber + "_" + id);
   //planthouse.getRow(row).getSection(sectionnumber).getPlants().add(cocktailtomato);
   //System.out.println("ID: ");
   //Cocktailtomatos cocktailtomato = new Cocktailtomatos(id, row, sectionnumber, true, false, false, 0, 10);
   //planthouse.getRow(row).getSection(sectionnumber).getPlants().add(cocktailtomato);

   //Cocktailtomatos cocktailtomato = Cocktailtomatos.createCocktailtomato(id, row, sectionnumber);
   //planthouse.getRow(row).getSection(sectionnumber).addPlants(cocktailtomato);

    planthouse.getRow(row).getSection(sectionnumber).addPlant(id, row, sectionnumber);
   //this.getPlantlist();
}

public int getPlantlist() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input row:");
    String row = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input sectionnumber:");
    Integer sectionnumber = scanner.nextInt();
   //return planthouse.getRow(row).getSection(sectionnumber).getPlants();
   //System.out.println(planthouse.getRow(row).getSection(sectionnumber).getPlants().size());
   System.out.println(planthouse.getRows());


       //System.out.println(planthouse.getRow("A").getSections().size());
       //for(int i=0; i<planthouse.getRow("A").getSections().size(); i++){
           //System.out.println(planthouse.getRow("A").getSections().get(i).getPlants());
       //}
       //for(int i=0; i<planthouse.getRows().size(); i++){


           // System.out.println(planthouse.getRows().get(i));
      // }

     return planthouse.getRow(row).getSection(sectionnumber).getPlants().size();
   }

  }





 public class Planthouse {
    private ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();

public Planthouse(){
    this.initRows();

}

public Planthouse(ArrayList<Row> rows) {
    this.setRows(rows);
}

public ArrayList<Row> getRows() {
    return rows;
}

private void initRows() {
    this.rows= new ArrayList<>();
    this.rows.add(new Row("A"));
    this.rows.add(new Row("B"));
    this.rows.add(new Row("C"));
    this.rows.add(new Row("D"));
    this.rows.add(new Row("E"));
    this.rows.add(new Row("F"));




}

public void setRows(ArrayList<Row> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

public void printPlanthouse(){
    for(Row row: rows) {
        System.out.println(row.getId());
        row.printSections();
    }

}


public Row getRow(String rowId) {
    Row row = new Row(rowId);
    return row;

}

    public void addPlant(){

    }

    public Section getSection(Row row, Section section) {
    Planthouse planthouse = new Planthouse();
    planthouse.getRow(row.getId()).getSection(section.getNumber());
    return section;
    }
}

 public class Row {
private String id;
private ArrayList<Section> sections;

public Row(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.initSections();

}

public Row(String id, ArrayList<Section> sections) {
    this.id = id;
    this.setSections(sections);

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ArrayList<Section> getSections() {
    return sections;
}

public void setSections(ArrayList<Section> sections) {
    this.sections = sections;
}


public void initSections() {
    this.sections = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <=25; i++) {
           this.sections.add(new Section(i));


        }

   }

    public void printSections() {
        for (Section section : sections) {
            System.out.println(section.getNumber());
        }
    }
    public Row(){

    }

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Row{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", sections=" + sections +
            '}';
}

public Section getSection(int sectionnumber){

    //Section section = new Section(sectionnumber);
    Section section = sections.get(sectionnumber-1);

    return section;

}
}
```

Method getPlantList() prints out all rows with its sections and each section with its plants, and after user adds a plant into section these sections are being printed empty (without plants). So I  come to conclusion that either plant is not created or not added to an arraylist. Can someone suggest me where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: You need to add PlantHouse class too here.

Comment: Done. Could you please look now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current `getRow` creates everytime a new Row not placed in the entire data hierarchy.

```
public Row getRow(String rowId) {
    for (Row row : rows) {
        if (row.getId().equals(rowId)) {
            return row;
        }
    }
    // Either throw new IllegalArgumentException(); or:
    Row row = new Row(rowId);
    rows.add(row);
    return row;
}
```

Instead, or additionally to a list you might want to use a Map from rowId to a Row.

```
Map<String, Row> rowMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Row> rowMap = new TreeMap<>(); // Sorted
Map<String, Row> rowMap = new LinkHashMap<>(); // In order of insertion, chronological

String rowId = "A";
rowMap.put(rowId, row);
Row row = rowMap.get(rowId);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, problem solved with editing a getRow method as you showed above!